# Error installing packages on Raspberry PI 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-stretch

When I'am trying to install packages I am getting error: `The value 'jessie' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources`

```
cat /etc/debian_version
9.8

cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux" 
VERSION_ID="9" 
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian 
ID_LIKE=debian

cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

I need tcl 8.5 or newer in order to run the Redis test. Does anyone know how do I resolve this error?

Comment: Hello, could you also include the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` to your question? Also, has your Pi always been "Stretch" or have your upgraded it from "Jessie" at all?

Comment: @RogerJones here is my result for `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi

Answer (score 1):

Although your `sources.list` seems to be using the correct release codename, check for any files listed under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` as well. They should each be using "stretch" or "stable", edit them as needed.

When you're done run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` to update the system. If you have changed any of the `sources` files from "jessie" then it might be worth giving `sudo apt dist-upgrade` a run as well before trying to install Tcl 8.5 again.

Comment: @Dirk, I stand corrected. I don't have a Pi to hand right now so used [this](https://raspbian.org/RaspbianRepository) as my source for the URI (changing the release codename as appropriate). Of course OP's `sources.list` is using "stretch" anyway so would not explain the error. The more I think about it, the answer I've given is misleading at best: I'll edit it to focus on the `sources.list.d` directory.